# Sphinx documentation: ERROR: Unknown directive type "program-output"

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm trying to create my docs with Sphinx, and now on two machines I have the exact same problem: the program-output directive does not work.

I installed Sphinx, then the programoutput extension:

```
$ sudo pip install sphinxcontrib-programoutput
```

The installation went fine, documents compile beautifully to nice looking html, but the command-output just doesn't work.

I created a super-simple test case with a file called `test.rst` containing a single line:

```
.. program-output:: python -V
```

Now when trying to compile this, I get the following output (path abbreviated):

```
/path/to/test.rst:1: ERROR: Unknown directive type "program-output".
```

Changing program-output to it's alias command-output doesn't work either (not surprising). I really wonder what I'm doing wrong here. I followed the installation instructions, tried it again and again, reinstalled with an `--upgrade` flag, nothing works.

Comment: did you added `sphinxcontrib-programoutput` in your `conf.py`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to bmu I found the problem, indeed I had to add it to the conf.py.

Now the next question: "why is this not in the installation/usage documentation of this extension?" It's not mentioned in http://packages.python.org/sphinxcontrib-programoutput/ which is the first link I get when googling for this extension.

Anyway the complete answer, hope it's useful for other people too:

Go to the document root of your documentation (e.g. `~/Projects/project-name/doc`) where the rest of your documents are.

Edit file `conf.py`

Look for the line that says `extensions = []` (an empty list in my case)

Change this to: `extensions = ['sphinxcontrib.programoutput']`

And miraculously it suddenly starts to work.

Comment: you should post this as another question or update your question.