# Sphinx error: Unknown directive type "automodule" or "autoclass"

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

I need to document my Python project using Sphinx. But I can't use `autodoc`.

When I config my project I select the option "extension autodoc", but now if I use

```
.. autoclass:: Class
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: Unknown directive type "autoclass"
```

I configure the `PYTHONPATH`, and now it's good. But I already have this problem.

My index file is:

```
.. ATOM documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Thu Nov 22 15:24:42 2012.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to ATOM's documentation!
================================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

.. automodule:: atom

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Comment: Is "sphinx.ext.autodoc" included in the [`extensions`](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html?highlight=extensions#confval-extensions) configuration variable in conf.py?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The same thing happened to me! To fix it, go to the line in conf.py that says something like this:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode']
```

Yours will probably look different. Anyway, add `'sphinx.ext.autodoc'` to the list. e.g.

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode', 'sphinx.ext.autodoc']
```

If it was:

```
extensions = []
```

then you'd change it to:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
```

Sources: [Sphinx documentation: ERROR: Unknown directive type "program-output"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842285/sphinx-documentation-error-unknown-directive-type-program-output)