# How to add to setup.cfg the extensions block

Tags: python, python-sphinx

In my Python project I have only **setup.cfg** and **pyproject.toml** configuration files and I don't want to add **setup.py**. But I want to use Sphinx package and it requires to add the extensions block to the *setup.py* (like [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516404/sphinx-error-unknown-directive-type-automodule-or-autoclass)):

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode', 'sphinx.ext.autodoc']
```

So how can I add this section to the *setup.cfg*?

Comment: `extensions = [...]` is a setting for Sphinx's conf.py. Do you really need to add it to another file?

Comment: Do you mean use the Sphinx package, or a Sphinx extension? It looks like you want the latter, in which case that goes in your Sphinx's configuration file `conf.py`.

Comment: I'm new in Python, but put configurations to the code file is sounds very strange and I see that it's going to change on the last time (pyproject.toml is a new configuration file introduced by PEP 517 and PEP 518), so I wouldn't like to add setup.py to the new project. But seems I have no choice, I need documentation package.

Comment: @mzjn you are absolutely right, it says about  Sphinx's  its own conf.py in the /docs folder, and not my main conf.py