# Docker sphinxdoc/sphinx does not find built-in sphinx extension (path not set...)

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I created a software documentation using restructuredText and sphinx, which shall be uploaded to a gitlab repository and connected to readthedocs.

Locally I can create the html documentation. However, when I upload it to a gitlab repository, and create a CI with a sphinxdoc/sphinx docker container, it does not find the build-in extensions (I use todo and ifconfig). The reason is that locally I use

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('/home/scheider/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/ext'))
```

in my `conf.py` in order to include the extensions, but I don't know what to use for the gitlab CI.

Sorry, if it is a stupid questions, but my knowledge about docker is very(!) limited.
Thanks in advance for any help
Ingo

I used the sphinxdoc/sphinx docker also locally and got the same error. Since I cannot work with the docker container interactively, I don't know how to get the respective path (and it seems that my google skills are minor as well...)

Comment: In conf.py, you need to specify the extensions that you want to use: `extensions = ["sphinx.ext.todo", "sphinx.ext.ifconfig"]`. Basically the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/13516404/407651.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Sorry that I did not find the mentioned query.